# Find missing values from tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find a combination of values from three columns that exist in table A and *Not* in Table B. My code keeps blowing up on the where clause with Address comma. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT a.Address,a.Last_Name_First_Name,a.Actual_Sale_Date
FROM salesdataall a
WHERE a.Address, a.Last_Name_First_Name, a.Actual_Sale_Date
NOT IN (SELECT b.Address,b.Last_Name_First_Name,b.Actual_Sale_Date
                      FROM salesdataun b)


ERROR:  syntax error at or near ,
LINE 3:  WHERE a.Address,a.Last_Name_First_Name,a.A...
                        ^
```

Comment: An easier to read way would be to use NOT EXISTS or INTERSECTION

Comment: @ Milney, you are absolutely correct. Totally forgot about it. Except would also work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses:

```
SELECT a.Address,a.Last_Name_First_Name,a.Actual_Sale_Date
FROM salesdataall a
WHERE (a.Address, a.Last_Name_First_Name, a.Actual_Sale_Date)
      NOT IN (SELECT b.Address,b.Last_Name_First_Name,b.Actual_Sale_Date
              FROM salesdataun b)
```

This is one of the rare situations where it makes sense to put parentheses around a list of columns.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a join:

```
SELECT a.Address,a.Last_Name_First_Name,a.Actual_Sale_Date
FROM salesdataall a
LEFT JOIN salesdataun b
ON a.Address = b.Address AND
   a.Last_Name_First_Name = b.Last_Name_First_Name AND
   a.Actual_Sale_Date = b.Actual_Sale_Date
WHERE a.Address IS NULL
```